# Shortcut for "my_var.condition ? statement : my_var"

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I have this statement :

```
username.blank? ? firstname : username
```

There is a shortcut or a way to avoid repeating 'username' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems you're using `ActiveSupport`, there is simple way to do this:

```
username.presence || firstname
```

Comment: Oh, neat. You learn something new every day.

Comment: +1. I knew this functions have some useful application!